# How to write batch file for copying anydrive folder to some otherdrive

Tags: batch-file

I have two folders in one drive and this is copy to some other drive folder.drive paths must be relative ,How to write batch file in this scinario
eg: source folder : E:/new
    destination folder: c:/sample

both paths must be realtive

Could you please help anyone to solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

If `e:\new` is the current folder in drive `e:` and `c:\sample` is the current folder in drive `c:`, then

```
robocopy e: c: /e
```

should do the required work: Copy from current folder in `e:` to current folder in `c:` including subdirectories

Comment: Thank you for your response.If both are relative paths how write this one

Comment: @VSN it is using relative paths. As relatives as it uses no explicit paths, assumes the current path. If you want explicit relative paths, then there is a question to answer: paths relative to what?